# WIX HeatProject, how to use visual studio 2010

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3.6

I have recently converted visual studio setup projects to wix project. Everything great, except that you have to ist every file manually.
 Is there something similar to adding project output (VS studio setup project). I read something about HeatProject task but don't know how to use it, could not find any documentation or example of the same.
First question,is it possible to add project output instead of adding files one by one if yes then how?

Answer (score 1):

Heat offers same functionality like tallow, or [paraffin](http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2007/10/21/wix-a-better-tallow-paraffin.aspx). Paraffin will generate .wxs fragment file containing list of all files which will be deployed. Using parameters you can set which files you want and more.

Example

```
%1\Paraffin.exe -dir "..\..\..\..\Web\HostDir" -dirref INSTALLLOC -custom APPL ..\..\WebFragment.wxs -guids -ext .csproj -direXclude obj -multiple
```

Answer (score 1):

We use heat.exe to harvest our app files as follows. The %FULL_PUBLISH_PATH% is the full path to the directory that we instructed msbuild to publish the webapp to.

```
"%WIX_TOOLS_PATH%heat.exe" dir %FULL_PUBLISH_PATH% -dr WEBAPPLOC -ke -srd -cg ComponentNameToUse -var var.publishDir -gg -out FileNameToUse.wxs
```